# How to allow sql request to clients on Azure datalake

Tags: sql, request, azure-databricks, delta-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I use Azure datalake gen 2, I transform data with databricks and I have delta tables which are sent in Power BI. But the clients have to be allowed to request in sql my tables.
What is the best practice ? Is it possible with databricks or have I to use something else ?
Thank you in advance for helping me !!

Answer (score 0):

With premium workspace, you could let Users Credentials pass through to storage account form within Azure Databricks.
Go to **Compute** --> **Cluster** --> **Advanced options**, you'll see a check box **Enable credential passthrough for user-level data access** (refer screenshot)

[image]